# Sort a nested hash based on one of the values of the of the final hash

Tags: perl, sorting, hash

I have a nested hash as follows

```
$hash{$key1}{$key2}{$key3} = value;
```

```
my %hash = (
    name1 => {
        a => { line => 4, page => 112 },
        b => { line => 6, page => 134 },
        c => { line => 1, page => 112 }
    },
    name2 => {
        a => { line => 43, page => 112 },
        b => { line => 12, page => 134 },
        c => { line => 55, page => 112 }
    }
)
```

I want to sort `key2` according to ascending values in `line`. i.e. `name1` should have `key2` arranged as `c`, `a`, `b` and `name2` should have the order `b`, `a`, `c`.

I know hashes always give random pairs, but is there any way to do a systematic arrangement of the values to get sorted keys?

Comment: You can sort on the fly, when you use hashes, to generate lists that you may need to store or iterate over. Did you try with [sort](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/sort.html)?  There are many posts around SO showing how to do more complex sorting, by different parts of complex data structures, by complex and/or multiple criteria, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only arrays can store a set of values in a specific order

I think this is what you're looking for. For each value of `$key1` it stores the sorted values of `$key2` in an array and prints them

```
use strict;
use warnings 'all';

my %hash = (
    name1 => {
        a => { line => 4, page => 112 },
        b => { line => 6, page => 134 },
        c => { line => 1, page => 112 },
    },
    name2 => {
        a => { line => 43, page => 112 },
        b => { line => 12, page => 134 },
        c => { line => 55, page => 112 },
    },
);

for my $key1 ( sort keys %hash ) {
    my $h2 = $hash{$key1};
    my @key2 = sort { $h2->{$a}{line} <=> $h2->{$b}{line} } keys %$h2;
    print "$key1: @key2\n";
}
```

#### output

```
name1: c a b
name2: b a c
```

Comment: Thanks. This helps very much.

Answer (score 1):

Hash keys are not guaranteed to be stored in any specific order but you can create a dedicated index array (a hash of array references in your case), which would store the keys ordered as desired:

```
my %sorted;
foreach my $key1 (keys %hash) {
    $sorted{$key1} = [ 
        sort { 
            $hash{$key1}{$a}{"line"} 
            <=> 
            $hash{$key1}{$b}{"line"} 
        } keys $hash{$key1} 
    ];
}
```

Then you may use the `@{$sorted{$key1}}` index array this way, for instance:

```
foreach my $key1 (keys %hash) {
    foreach my $key2 (@{$sorted{$key1}}) {
        print "$key1.$key2: "
            ."line: $hash{$key1}{$key2}{'line'}, "
            ."page: $hash{$key1}{$key2}{'page'}\n";
    }
}
```

Output:

```
name2.b: line: 12, page: 134
name2.a: line: 43, page: 112
name2.c: line: 55, page: 112
name1.c: line: 1, page: 112
name1.a: line: 4, page: 112
name1.b: line: 6, page: 134
```

Comment: Thanks for the help sir.